# Get the file name and the extension while uploading file in PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova

I am uploding an image from a gallery using *PhoneGap* in Android but what I want to do is to fetch the file name and its extension which i am not be able to get it from *imageuri* so can any one tell me how can I find one

my `imageURI` is `content://media/external/images/media/876` so is there a way to get a fileEntry by using this `imageURI` and read the file name and extension ?

```
function fileUpload(){

    navigator.camera.getPicture(
                uploadPhoto,
                function(message) { alert('get picture failed'); },
                {
                    quality         : 50,
                    destinationType : navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
                    sourceType      : navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
                }
            );


   }
    function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
            var options = new FileUploadOptions();
            options.fileKey="uploaded_file";
            alert(imageURI);
            options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
            options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

            var params = new Object();
            params.value1 = "test";
            params.value2 = "param";

            options.params = params;

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("http://www.mydomain.com/mobile_upload.php"), win, fail, options);
        }

        function win(r) {

            alert("WIN" +r.response);
            console.log("Code = " + r.responseCode);
            console.log("Response = " + r.response);
            console.log("Sent = " + r.bytesSent);
        }

        function fail(error) {

                    alert("error");

            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
            console.log("upload error source " + error.source);
            console.log("upload error target " + error.target);
        }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22266951/9807508 this really helped thanks alot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the answer and here is the code

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(imageURI, function(entry){

                console.log("****************HERE YOU WILL GET THE NAME AND OTHER PROPERTIES***********************");
                console.log(entry.name + " " +entry.fullPath);

            }, function(e){



            });
```

Comment: this does not work on for whatever reason on cordova 3.4. I have been unable to get a regular uri with extensions ...very frustrating

Comment: Can anyone confirm this is working on Phonegap 3.4 with Android devices? ... I don't want to open an new SO question.

Comment: You can retrieve the real local destination with filename in this example by doing entry.toURL()

Comment: Does NOT work! Neither `fullPath` nor `toURL()` contain file extension.

Comment: @hunt not working on cordova showing native url instead of actual file name.

Comment: For those who are still looking for another answers, checkout my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41038785/2304737

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and think that I found a solution. I think it is not the best, but possible ;-)

After get File_URI from camera resolve File system from File_URI and in this fileEntry get file. This file (here filee) is a variable called type, this is the mime type of file.

> ```
>         function clickEvent() {
>
>             navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
>                 destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
>                 sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM
>             });
>         }
>
>         function cameraSuccess(file_URI) {
>             window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(file_URI, function(fileEntry) {
>                 fileEntry.file(function(filee) {
>                     alert(filee.type); //THIS IS MIME TYPE
>                 }, function() {
>                     alert('error');
>                 });
>
>             }, onError);
>         }
>
>         function onError() {
>             alert('fehler resolve file system');
>         }
>
>         function cameraError() {
>             alert('fehler');
>         }
> ```